# NoCache, NoStore and must-revalidate cache header in asp.net core via middleware

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to add no-store must-revalidate no-cache in my web api project of asp.net core 3.1 in middle ware
I have added following

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/error-local-development");
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
            }
          
            app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
                      new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
                      {
                          NoCache = true,
                          NoStore = true,
                          MustRevalidate = true
                      };

                if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Forwarded-Prefix", out var value))
                    context.Request.PathBase = value.First();

                return next();
            });
.....
}
```

But on my api response header is coming like

```
access-control-allow-origin: * 
 cache-control: no-storemust-revalidateno-cache
 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
 date: Fri12 Mar 2021 12:23:06 GMT 
 server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 
 transfer-encoding: chunked 
 x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

Can anyone help why headervalue are concatenated and how i can add spaces between them

Comment: Does the issue just occur in this project? If you create a new project with same code of adding headers to control caching, does it work well?

Comment: i have to check this. i think your thought is regarding some dependency

Comment: Hi @KamranShahid, glad to hear the problem is resolved, you can mark the reply as answer, which would help other community members quickly find this thread and resolve similar issue.

Comment: @FeiHan i have added an answer with detail about swagger ui problem. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PRoblem is in swagger ui response interface. looks like it skips commas. thanks Fei Han for the hint to test another project